# MinGW - make: cc: Command not found

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw

I have recently started using MinGW and I am having trouble getting `make` working on Windows. My directory structure is like this:

```
Makefile
p001.cpp
p002.cpp
p003.cpp
bin\
```

My `Makefile` looks like this:

```
CC=g++
BIN=bin

%: p%.cpp
    $(CC) p$*.cpp -o $(BIN)/p$*
```

However when I use `make` I get the error:

```
> make 001
cc p001.cpp -o bin/p001
make: cc: Command not found
make: *** [001] Error 127
```

I am not sure what is wrong here. From what I have read, the variable `CC` defaults to `cc` when the specified compiler is not found. I don't see why that is the case. `g++` is in my system path variable, and just using `g++ p001.cpp -o bin/p001` works fine.

Comment: Have you added the mingw/bin in the system path? Which g++ are you using ?

Comment: Yes, the bin folder is in system path. `g++` version is 4.9.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP here. I was able to resolve the problem simply by putting a comment line/empty line at the beginning of the makefile. It worked fine after that. I do not yet know why that is the case. My modified makefile looks like:

```
# this is a comment
CC=g++
BIN=bin

%: p%.cpp
    $(CC) p$*.cpp -o $(BIN)/p$*
```

Comment: The "new line" helped me too ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$(CXX)` when invoking the C++ compiler. `$(CC)` is for compiling C code.

MinGW doesn't come with `cc` so `$(CC)` will not work. You should define it to `gcc` in as an environment variable to make it work. Another option is making a copy of gcc.exe to cc.exe

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you're trying to do with this, but I assume you're trying to do something like this:

```
CC=g++
BIN=bin

all: p

p: p001.o p002.o p003.o
    $(CC) -o $(BIN)/program.exe p001.o p002.o p003.o

p001.o: p001.cpp
    $(CC) -c p001.cpp

p002.o: p002.cpp
    $(CC) -c p002.cpp

p003.o: p003.cpp
    $(CC) -c p003.cpp
```

Comment: Essentially what I am trying to do is this: all files follow a naming pattern `p<NUMBER>.cpp` and have no dependencies. So when I type `make 003`, it compiles the file `p003.cpp`.